# How does "Auto Update" / "Check for Update" work?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, auto-update

this is my first time writing a desktop application.

Currently, I am using Jetpack Compose as a framework, so I am wondering

1. How actually does those desktop application's "Check for Update" work?
2. How can I write one in Jetpack Compose / Kotlin, is that need a server for that?
3. Can I use Javascript with Netlify for the updater server?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the "jetpack" tag and remove the "jvm" tag?

Comment: @boneill but it is part of jvm, SO's jetpack tag is for android only

Comment: Jetpack isn't feature of the jvm. I have a match rule for jvm, and this question isn't really about the jvm directly. I'm suggesting alternate tags to help you reach the right people who can answer your question.

Comment: `Jetpack Compose` is not a desktop application framework, but a toolkit for building native Android UI. What makes you think that *those desktop application's "Check for Update"* feature relies on `Jetpack Compose`? By the way, what applications specifically you're talking about?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь it is a framework, I assume because it's still in the alpha stage so no one aware? Check this out: https://blog.frankel.ch/state-jvm-desktop-frameworks/5. I know how does it work now. Thanks for your help!